# can I disable hyperlink in an if statement

Tags: jquery

Below is the code where it looks to see if the number of rows added matches a number. E.g If the number is 5 , then if 5 rows has been added...

```
 if (qnum == <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) {

//...code

    }
```

I want to disable a hyperlink after the user adds the maximum number of rows they are allowed to add, then will it work if I put the .click() function in the if statement like below:

```
  if (qnum == <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) {
    $(".showGrid").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
}
```

the hyperlink is below;

```
<span href="#" class="showGrid">[Open Grid]</span>
```

Comment: In the future, please post the actual code that pertains to the situation. In this case we never saw the event binding code that you wanted to unbind. You will receive higher quality answers if you post higher quality questions.

Comment: ...I just realized this is the code you've been asking questions about for months (?). Is this a homework assignment that keeps changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would unbind all other click handlers first and then `preventDefault()` and I would `return false;` as well.

```
if (qnum == <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) {
    $(".showGrid").unbind('click').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }).css('color', '#BBBBBB');
}
```

Comment: `return false;` is the same as `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. So you don't need `event.preventDefault()` if you are also using `return false`.

Comment: I was under the impression that `preventDefault()` also called `event.stopPropagation` or set `event.cancelBubble = true` depending on the browser.

Comment: That doesn't disable the hyperlink as well

Comment: No, but it does prevent anything from actually happening. To disable it entirely, you could probably give it a `disabled="disabled"` attribute.

Comment: sorry, it did work, I didn't include return false last time but when I include it then it worked.

Comment: one little question, how can I change hyperlink color so that when it is disabled, it displays the hyperlink in a grey color?

Comment: just chain a `.css('color', '#BBBBBB')` (or your preferred hex color) onto the end of it. I've updated the answer to reflect that.